# Join Tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables: **Company** & **Users**.

I have a form in which  i insert Company name and others details. in that same form i  have a sub form Sales info and Tech info.

The data i insert in sales and tech info gets stored into users tables.and their id are stored into company table in two fields called sales_id and tech_id.

Now for a view i want to fetch company name its sales person and its tech person,How to do it?

The Code in model:

```
        public function get_company()
    {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->join('users','users.id = company.sales_id','users.id = company.tech_id');
        $this->db->from('company');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result(); 
        return $result; 

    }
```

IN The View:

```
<?php if(count($companys)): foreach($companys as $company): ?>  

  <td><?php echo $company->first_name; ?></td>
```

how to differentiate which is sales and which is tech person?

the Controller:

```
public function add_company($id = NULL)
    {

        $this->data['company'] = $this->company_m->get_new();
        $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_new();
        $rules = $this->company_m->rules_admin;

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {



            /*Inserting  Sales Person Information*/

            $data['first_name'] = $this->input->post('first_name_s');

            $data['last_name'] = $this->input->post('last_name_s');

            $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email_s');

            $data['user_type'] ="sales";

            $this->user_m->save($data,$id);

            $sales_id = $this->db->insert_id();



            /*Inserting  Tech Person Information*/
            $data_tech =$this->user_m->array_from_post(array('first_name','last_name','email'));


            $this->user_m->save($data_tech,$id);

            $tech_id = $this->db->insert_id();



            /*Insert Company Information*/

            $data = $this->company_m->array_from_post(array('org_name','dba','addr1','addr2','city','state','country','pin','sales_id','tech_id','tax_number','comment','url'));

            $data['sales_id']= $sales_id;

            $data['tech_id']= $tech_id;

            $org_id = $this->company_m->save($data, $id); 

            redirect('admin/company');


        }
                                            // Load the view
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/company/add';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);

    }
```

I hope you understood my issue.

The Company table
[image: company tabb;e]

The Users table

[image: users]

the View code:

```
<table class="table table-striped ">
            <thead>
                <tr class="warning">


                    <th>Organization Name</th>
                    <th>Sales Person</th>
                    <th>Tech Person</th>
                    <th>Tax No</th>


                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php if(count($companys)): foreach($companys as $company): ?>  
               <tr class="active">

        <td  contenteditable="true" onClick="edit_company(this)" onBlur="save_company(this,'org_name','<?php echo $company->id; ?>')" ><?php echo $company->org_name; ?></td>
        <td  contenteditable="true" onClick="edit_company(this)" onBlur="save_company(this,'sales_id','<?php echo $company->id; ?>')" ><?php echo $company->first_name; ?></td>
        <td  contenteditable="true" onClick="edit_company(this)" onBlur="save_company(this,'tech_id','<?php echo $company->id; ?>')" ><?php echo $company->first_name; ?></td>
        <td  contenteditable="true" onClick="edit_company(this)" onBlur="save_company(this,'tax_number','<?php echo $company->id; ?>')" ><?php echo $company->tax_number; ?></td>


                <td><?php echo btn_edit('admin/company/edit/' . $company->id); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo btn_delete('admin/company/delete/' . $company->id); ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">We could not find any users.</td>
            </tr>
    <?php endif; ?> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you share three table structure ?

Comment: If I am correct you want the sales name, tech name and company name ?

Comment: @killstreet yes thats how i want to show

Comment: if(isset($company->sales_id) && $company->sales_id != '' && $company->sales_id != 'NULL') { echo "sales person"; }  if(isset($company->tech_id) && $company->tech_id != '' && $company->tech_id != 'NULL') { echo "tech person";  }

Comment: @VairaMuthu added the table stuct

Comment: @VairaMuthu can you please post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In model Use

```
  public function get_company()
    {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('company');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result(); 
        return $result; 

    }
```

For view :-

```
 <?php if(count($companys)): foreach($companys as $company):
 $tech_person = $this->db->get_where("users",array("id"=>$company->tech_id))->row();
        $sales_person = $this->db->get_where("users",array("id"=>$company->sales_id))->row();
 ?>  
           <tr class="active">

    <td  contenteditable="true" onClick="edit_company(this)" onBlur="save_company(this,'org_name','<?php echo $company->id; ?>')" ><?php echo $company->org_name; ?></td>
    <td  contenteditable="true" onClick="edit_company(this)" onBlur="save_company(this,'sales_id','<?php echo $company->id; ?>')" ><?php echo $tech_person->first_name; ?></td>
    <td  contenteditable="true" onClick="edit_company(this)" onBlur="save_company(this,'tech_id','<?php echo $company->id; ?>')" ><?php echo $sales_person->first_name; ?></td>
    <td  contenteditable="true" onClick="edit_company(this)" onBlur="save_company(this,'tax_number','<?php echo $company->id; ?>')" ><?php echo $company->tax_number; ?></td>


            <td><?php echo btn_edit('admin/company/edit/' . $company->id); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo btn_delete('admin/company/delete/' . $company->id); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">We could not find any users.</td>
        </tr>
<?php endif; ?> 
        </tbody>
```

**In this method you even do not need join to get tech and sales person.**
Edited According to your view

Comment: this sounds logical! can you edit my code for the same i am adding the view code in question please update you answer accordinglt

Comment: can you please tell me how to show this in table the answer you gave sounds perfect

Comment: @Rajan Glad to know that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

At first move the code your have in the controller to a model. If you use a MVC framework try and use it for what it's built, it will help keep everything clean.

So now in the model you should have the following:

```
function getCompany(){
    $query = $this->db->select('users.first_name, company.org_name')
    ->from('company')
    ->join('users','users.id = company.sales_id','users.id = company.tech_id')
    ->get()
    ->result_array(); 
    return $query; 
}
```

In your view you would do the following:

```
<?php if(count($companys)): foreach($companys as $company): ?>  
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $company['first_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $company['org_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; endif;?>
```

Comment: Oh okay, got confused because in the question it said controller

Comment: okay sorry but how to show my tech person? it still returns same for both sales person and tech person

Comment: There is no table that shows what the tech table looks like, update the question with the tech table and I will update the awnser

Comment: i just have two tables one is company and other is users, when i add a company i add sales person and tech person for that company, and its stored in users table, the first record inserted would be sales and second would be tech and then will get the in of both inserted record and save it in company table

Comment: i am adding the add method in question so u can undertstand